# App uses https - what is the correct value of ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

The ONLY encryption my App uses is calls over HTTPS. Currently (7 June 2017) iTunes Connect requires an Export Compliance according to this information in iTunes Connect.

[image]

I've entered the iTunesConnect -> My Apps -> Features -> Encryption page, clicked the plus symbol besides "iOS Documentation" and in the Export Compliance form answered YES.

[image]

The following two screen shots show more details of the export compliance box as I scroll down.

[image][image]

The last 2 screen shots suggest using HTTPS is an EXEMPT use of encryption and I should therefore in info.plist set ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption=false. But this is not clear, and is contradicted in my 1st screen shot that says *if you are making a call to HTTPS ... required to submit a year-end classification report to the US government*.

So my questions:

1. is it correct to set ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption=false if the only encryption I use is via HTTPS calls?
2. if I must set ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption=true, where do I go to submit a report to the US government and how does this report get passed to Apple? I cannot find any clear information on the process. I don't want to screw this up as the consequences can be major as threatened in the last screen shot.
3. regardless of how I set ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption, according to my 1st screen shot if I use HTTPS I must submit a year-end self classification to the US government. Is that true, and what is the process? (clicking the "learn more" link doesn't help)

Comment: I am also having same questions, any update on this ?  Can we submit app(which uses https calls) by adding ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption=false and How this works "if I use HTTPS I must submit a year-end self classification to the US government."

Comment: am here to complain. who wrote those notices anyway? its like a tongue twister gone wrong. definitely not something you'd want to twist and turn when legal is involved. i guess they cant justify their high pay with common english.

Answer (score 54):

I was searching the web for this for some hours. Actually it is pretty easy and you can verify this in itunes connect:

**1. All you have to do**

If your app uses only HTTPS or uses encryption only for authentication, tokens, etc., **there is nothing you have to do, just include**

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```

in your Info.plist and you are **done**.

**2. Verification**

You can **verify** this in itunes connect.

- select your app
- chose features
- chose encryption
- click "+"
- follow the dialog
- for https or authentication the answer is **yes** and **yes**

**3. Year-end self classification report**

As is written in the dialog in `2.`, you still need to submit a year-end self classification report:

> If you are making use of ATS or making a call to HTTPS please note
>   that you are required to submit a year-end self classification report
>   to the US government. [Learn more](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/4-reports-and-reviews/a-annual-self-classification)

You can check [How do I submit a Self Classification Report for Encryption Items](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/all-articles/15-policy-guidance/encryption/560-encryption-faqs#13) and this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48462458/276648 .

---

In any case you should of course **read yourself** carefully through the dialog.

A very **helpful article** can be found here:

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2017/02/itunes-connect-encryption-info/

Comment: Even though I added this entry in my plist I still go the prompt in App Store Connect to verify my compliance, so I'm not sure this does anything anymore.

Comment: sorry for ask, what happend if didnt report Annual Self-Classification Report? Is My App got revoke?

Comment: How the statement from point 1 (there is nothing you have to do, just include...) corresponds to point 3 (you still need to submit a year-end self classification report)?

Answer (score 10):

I unfortunately do not have enough rep to comment but at the minute I am looking into the exact same issue and I **believe** that you are correct when you say that you can set the ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption key to false, at least this was the conclusion I came to from my research.

For the self classification report it does look like you have to submit one by February of next year, I found this link helpful in explaining the report and what to do

https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/reports-and-reviews/annual-self-classification

Like I said this is all from my own investigation like you and I think this is correct but if anyone does have any more information would be greatly appreciated.