# Https, uiwebview and export compliance

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have some difficulties understanding the Export Compliance regarding to a build I made through xcode. 
To sum up, I made a responsive website to show with some images and videos. Since Apple doesn't allow an UIwebview that's not SSL I created my site with "let's encrypt". 
The app I sent as a build is only an UIwebview and nothing else. 
I'm not sure about the procedure from here since there's a lot back and forth how to manage it. Can somebody guide me in the right direction. Is it necessary to fill out or can I exempt?

Comment: Check that the Apple document station, I believe it states: *"Does your app meet any of the following: (a) Qualifies for one or more exemptions provided under category 5 part 2 (b) Use of encryption is limited to encryption within the operating system (iOS or macOS) (c) Only makes call(s) over HTTPS (d) App is made available only in the U.S. and/or Canada"*. It seems (c) covers your usage.

Answer (score 1):

If the app does not encrypt anything, that is only makes HTTPS requests and consumes data, there is essentiall no encryption used, the Apple OS does the HTTPS decryption, not your app.

Check that the Apple document station, I believe it states:

*"Does your app meet any of the following: (a) Qualifies for one or more exemptions provided under category 5 part 2 (b) Use of encryption is limited to encryption within the operating system (iOS or macOS) (c) Only makes call(s) over HTTPS (d) App is made available only in the U.S. and/or Canada"*.

It seems (c) covers your usage.

Comment: Thanks zaps. So I guess it's the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401899/app-uses-https-what-is-the-correct-value-of-itsappusesnonexemptencryption ? And would that leave me without doing that self classification report, because I have no clue on what to report since I don't catch any data.