# Annual Self-Classification Report

Tags: ios, eccn

Our iOS app only makes calls over https and nothing else, so we have to submit our self classification report. We filled out every field, but we don't know if the ECCN is 5D002 or 5D992 or 5D992.c or....? Can anyone tell us??? We have read a lot of documents but we can not figure it out.

Answer (score 13):

Although I'm not sure this question belongs on Stack Overflow, you more than likely need to enter `5D992` in the ECCN column. You cannot include the `.c` in this column, per [this guidance](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=1&SID=4150cfbf028e9a85574385383a581f47&h=L&mc=true&n=pt15.2.742&r=PART&ty=HTML#ap15.2.742_119.6).

If you are `5D002` and you meet the [mass market criteria](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/documents/new-encryption/1656-note-3-to-c5p2/file) (distribued solely on the App Store), then enter `5D992`.

See also: [Self-Classification Report Generator](https://annual-self-classification-report.github.io)

(I am not a lawyer.)

Comment: `solely on the App Store` - what if I have the same app in Google Play market?

Comment: We simply added the same line again to the csv and added Google Play and AppStore to the two lines. We did this the second year and everything seemed to be ok.

Comment: I emailed this documento to the email address in the instructions (https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/4-reports-and-reviews/a-annual-self-classification) a few days ago and now what do I do? Wait? This is so unclear.

Comment: Yep, you're right @greg, somehow I managed to submit it, thank you!

Comment: That Report Generator is pretty slick! Thanks for that link!

Comment: Does anyone know if the app is new, and I am ready to release it now, in July, do I need to wait until January to write this e-mail with the self-classification report, or do I send the email now?

Comment: sorry for ask, what happend if didnt report Annual Self-Classification Report? Is My App got revoke?

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, as the other answer, an APP for general use, available in the store has likely ECCN `5D992` and is of type `MMKT` (Mass Market).

In case your app uses different and/or specific encryption technology (e.g. a VPN app, your own encryption libraries and so on) you might need a different classification.

As there are some references to this question I thought I added some links for the subject:

[Apple store connect information](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devc3f64248f)

[Blog with example](https://www.shippingsolutions.com/blog/export-encryption-reminders-for-year-end)

[Another blog with example](https://kitefaster.com/2017/08/10/encryption-export-compliance-ios-apps/)

[Actual US site on the ASCR](https://bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/4-reports-and-reviews/a-annual-self-classification)

> Be aware that you need to *check yourself* if all information is correct before you submit it.

Practical note: depending on your settings in Excel, your csv might not actually be using a 'comma' when you save it as a csv. Check that before you send it in!

Comment: Hey, I've just sent the annual export compliance. Approximately how long does it take before they answer so that I can upload it to upload it to apple so that the app can get published? thanks